# Is it possible to call a Java EE application (the ear) to be executed with a post commit hook (svn script)?

Tags: svn, jakarta-ee, hook, post-commit-hook

I need to call my Java EE application to be executed after the commit (in svn) so it can use some informations send from svn and other systems. Is it possible to write a post commit hook to call the ear of the app?

Comment: A hook script can do pretty much anything. It's only limited by the permissions of the account your Subversion server process executes under.

Comment: Okey i see that, but being a beginner i had no idea how to do it :( would anybody have some point or idea where i can start of ?